# NullPointer Exception when setting the adapter for a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I am trying to set the data to an adapter through an AsyncTask. This has caused alot of grief - Most recently when trying to set the Array Adapter.

The following method is called onPostExecute();

```
private void setQueues(final JSONObject[] qInfo) 
{
    queues = new QueueItem[qInfo.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < qInfo.length; i++)
    {
        queues[i] = new QueueItem();
        //final int ii = i;

        // Formatting the queue title
        String name = qInfo[i].optString("name").replace("-", " ");
        queues[i].label = name;

        try {
            if(qInfo[i].getString("active").contains("1"))
            {
                queues[i].value = true;
            }
            else
            {
                queues[i].value = false;
            }
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    lv.setAdapter(new QueueAdapter(getActivity(), 
            R.layout.queues_items, queues));
```

This causes the following exception runtime : [link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OQCw.png)

**EDIT :** As requested, here is QueueAdapter :

```
public class QueueAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<QueueItem>{

Context context; 
int layoutResourceId;    
QueueItem data[] = null;

public QueueAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, QueueItem[] data) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = data;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    QueueHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new QueueHolder();
        holder.queueswitch = (Switch)row.findViewById(R.id.queues_item_switch);
        holder.txtLabel = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.queues_item_text);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
    holder = (QueueHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    QueueItem queue = data[position];
    holder.txtLabel.setText(queue.label);
    holder.queueswitch.setChecked(queue.value);

    return row;
}

static class QueueHolder
{
    Switch queueswitch;
    TextView txtLabel;
}
}
```

Comment: check QueuesFragment class line number 98

Comment: seems there is a problem in QueueAdapter or queues_items code give the code

Comment: Are you sure you have called **new** on ListView??

Comment: I don't. I call lv = (ListView)getView().findViewById(R.id.queuesLayout); in onActivityCreated().

Answer (score 1):

```
lv.setAdapter(new QueueAdapter(getActivity(), 
            R.layout.queues_items, queues));
```

this snippet should be in try block.. Because If there is `JSONException` all elements in that array will be null...

I mean to say.. put for loop inside try block and not the oppt.. if you still want to loop when an Exception occurs.. Then Try using Collections instead of array..

Comment: True. But even if there isn't a JSONException it still causes a null pointer exception

Comment: @litemode.. you need to make sure that the elements in that array are not null in any case.. Why don't you try collections instead of Array.. Use an Hashtable which does't allow null values..

Comment: This does not answer my question. qInfo holds valid data in this case. so does QueueItem.